# What's the maximum speed that an object can reach given starting speed, distance and acceleration?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, physics

I'm new here and using this for my coding project, so please give answers in a simple form if possible!

I have a train. Let's say its moving at 50kph ($s$). The next speed board/marker is for 80kph ($v$) and it is 100 meters ($d$) away. My train accelerates/decelerates at a constant speed of 0.5m/s ($a$). If it starts accelerating now, what's the maximum speed ($m$) it will reach at the speed board?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Do you know the equation that relates initial velocity, acceleration, time and displacement?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have written code to find the distance and time required, so I don't know if that can be rearranged or if it needs to be rewritten. The formulas go as follows in my code: (targetSpeed-startSpeed)/acceleration = time; 0.5*(acceleration^2)*(time)^2 = distance.

Comment: Find the time it will take to reach at the marker and use that to find the velocity when you are crossing the marker.

Comment: @MathLover That's the next step unfortunately. Use the answer to my question to calculate the time required. (answer-startSpeed)/acceleration = time

Comment: It is still a lot more straightforward to first find time when you will reach the marker with max acceleration and use that to find max speed. I would suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the equation $v^{2}=u^{2}+2as$ where $v$ is the final (maximum in this case) velocity, $u$ is the initial velocity, and $a$ is the accelaration. This gives  $$v^{2}=13.8^{2}+2(0.5)(100)=292.89$$ (after converting km/h to m/s) and therefore $$v = (292.89)^{1/2} = 17.11~\text{m/s} = 61.6~\text{km/h}$$